# How can I change the highlighted color for selected options in an unfocused HTML select control?

Tags: html, css

I am able to change the highlighted color for each selected option when the select list is focused. But when the control is not focused it reverts to the standard grey. Can I arrange my style so that the color of selected items will be the same whether or not the list is focused. Here are a couple of screen shots:

**Focused:**

Toyota, Ford and Chevrolet are selected.

[image]

**Not Focused:**

The same three items are still selected, but just showing in grey which is the default color for a selected option in an unfocused select list.

[image]

Here is the complete code for my HTML page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <style>

        .btn-group {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
            overflow: hidden;
            border: solid grey 1px;
        }

        .btn-group select {
            margin: 0px -16px 0px 0px; /* pull in the right margin to obscure the scroll bar */
        }

        .btn-group option {
            background-color:lightblue;
            border: 1px solid blue; 
            color: black; 
            padding: 10px 24px; /* Some padding */
            cursor: pointer; /* Pointer/hand icon */
            float: left; /* Float the buttons side by side */
        }

        /* Clear floats (clearfix hack) */
        .btn-group:after {
            content: "";
            clear: both;
            display: table;
        }

        .btn-group option:not(:last-child) {
            border-right: none; /* Prevent double borders */
        }

        /* Add a background color on hover */
        .btn-group option:hover {
            background-color: lavender;
        }

    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div align="center">
        <select multiple size="5">
            <option>Toyota</option>
            <option>Honda</option>
            <option>Ford</option>
            <option>Chevrolet</option>
            <option>Nissan</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <hr />

    <div class="btn-group" align="center">
        <select multiple size="1">
            <option>Toyota</option>
            <option>Honda</option>
            <option>Ford</option>
            <option>Chevrolet</option>
            <option>Nissan</option>
        </select>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your horizontal select doesn't display well in Firefox (84.0.2, MacOS) - the controls are all on top of each other. In general styling native select elements is a bit of a pain, with lots of potential for browser and OS specific weirdness. Are you able to use different controls, such as a set of checkboxes and labels? Styling those is much easier and more reliable.

Comment: Hi Ben, can you give an example? We're just introducing this control into our app to support the common 'slicer' paradigm for drilling into datasets. We want a control which will support the expected Click, Shift-Click, Ctrl-Click interaction. So we're just starting to develop this. If there is a better approach, please point us in that direction.

Comment: If you want to support shift/ctrl/cmd clicking, then a select may be the better option. You can replicate the behaviour on a checkbox group with Javascript, but it's generally better to use the native behaviour where possible. As far as styling selects go, here's a good article on the details: https://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/select-css.html (it doesn't cover `multiple` selects, though). I guess it's a matter of whether you prefer easy styling or easy behaviour - I don't think you can have both!

Comment: you can target siblings and descendants in CSS.  It's really tricky and hackish to target a cousin.  I.e. if you have to first go up and then go down to get to the DOM element.  Can you use javascript?

Comment: @DCR Yes, we can use javascript. That's not my area of expertise but I have a team of developers (who will be joining this discussion). I'm doing some prototyping to give some direction as to how to approach this. Do you have a proposal which relies on javascript? It strikes me that we can either have an approach which handles the interactivity natively, but then the layout gets complex, or an approach where the layout is well under control but then regulating the interactivity is going to get complex. If only they would have anticipated the need for a horizontal selection list!

Comment: I think in JS it's pretty straight forward.  get the options each time an option is clicked on. you'll get an array back - check the value of each option and then change the background color in the select below.

Comment: @DCR I'm not sure I understand your suggestion. With a select control there's no issue managing the selection state - HTML does that natively; Click, Shift-Click and Ctrl-Click all behave as expected. But the layout is challenging. On the other hand, if I use separate controls, let's say a group of buttons, then I'll need to manually handle the Click, not a big deal - as you suggest. But will detecting and processing Ctrl-Click and Shift-Click be as manageable?